# Search by conditional grouping and logic?

Tags: r

I'm new and learning R. I'm trying to ask a question that I don't know the words for. 
Suppose I have a data frame such that:

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
Week=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
Variable=c(30,25,27,42,44,45,30,50,19))



  ID Week Variable
1  A    1       30
2  A    2       25
3  A    3       27
4  B    1       42
5  B    2       44
6  B    3       45
7  C    1       30
8  C    2       50
9  C    3       19
```

How can I find what is the average Variable at Week 2 for all ID that had Variable = 30 at Week 1?

For example, I would like the output in this example to = 37.5

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output?

Comment: I edited the post. Is that helpful?

Comment: @Absolute_Human i updated my answer, you dont need to use `lapply`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Step 1:*** Obtain the IDs which had Variable=30 in Week1

```
res<-  subset( df,Variable==30 & Week==1, ID )
```

The output is:

```
> res
  ID
1  A
7  C
```

***Step 2:***
 Get all their variables at week 2:

```
dt<-subset(df,ID %in% as.vector(unlist(res))  & Week==2  ,select=c(ID,Variable))
```

The output is:

```
  ID Variable
2  A       25
8  C       50
```

***Step 3:*** Get the mean:

```
  mean(dt$Variable)
```

The final output is:

```
37.5
```

---

In step 2 we have `ID %in% as.vector(unlist(res))`. **So, what does it mean?**

The %in% part simply is an operator which **returns true if it finds an ID inside the right handside vector.** For example, run the below sample:

```
  a<- 1:10

  b<-c(0,4,6,8,16)

  b %in% a
```

and the result is:

```
FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

So, the %in% operator returns a Boolean value for each element of `b`. **The result will be True if, that element exist in** `a`, otherwise it returns **False**. As you see 0 and 16 have False.

But, the point is, `a` should be vector, meanwhile `res` is a `data.frame` so, i need to first `unlist` it, and then consider it as a `vector` (`as.vector`).

In conclusion, `ID %in% as.vector(unlist(res))` checks if each ID exist in res or not.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I don't quite understand the code but I'm going to through it and try to learn what I can. This was a huge help- thanks for making it easy to follow.

Comment: @Absolute_Human you are very welcome. if you explain me, what part is not clear for you, i can exaplain more in my answer.

Comment: Well, I'm new to programming and R so a lot of what I don't know is basic. 

For example, I knew the function subset but I forgot how the arguments for it work until I read your answer and the help function in R. 

This is my first time seeing %in%, as.vector, and unlist which I'm learning about now. The help section in R isn't written in the most easy to understand text, so it's taking me a while to parse the meaning.

Comment: @Absolute_Human let me update my answer about `%in%` and `as.vector`

Comment: That was fantastic. You went above and beyond. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This might be easier to read/see.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  spread(Week, Variable) %>%
  filter(`1` == 30) %>%
  with(mean(`2`))

[1] 37.5
```

I think `tidyverse` code is easier to understand because you can read it left to right like you would any non-code text. And the piping `%>%` makes seeing the order of operations easier, no more parentheses to parse.

Answer (score 0):

First we need `ID`'s which have entry for `variable=30 AND week=1` and then from that `ID`'s extract `ID`'s with `Week=2` and do `avg(Variable)`

Base R Solution:

```
mean(df[df$ID %in% (df[df$Week==1 & df$Variable==30,1]) & df$Week==2,3])
```

Output:

```
[1] 37.5
```

**OR (another approach)**

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select avg(Variable) from df where ID IN (select ID from df where variable=30 AND week=1) AND Week=2")
```

Output:

```
    avg(Variable)
1          37.5
```

Comment: I'm slow at reading code, I will try to understand this then get back to you! Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm still too new to programming to understand. for the base R solution I'm not sure what the 1 after the 30 and  the 3 after the 2 are doing in the code. 

I also don't sql. I think I'm going to try a few more tutorials and come back to your answer- hopefully I'll get it then.